# Cryptic Cryptography

Tags: cipher

On the first day of my new job, I arrived to find a odd note on my desk.
It has a cryptic phrase and some jumbled letters.

> "Reflection on the past gives insight into new angles of approach."
>
> Crcuyseygmucxcg hc xyxwwwu abm yyfn! Lnj ciwa uhgkas mnjmkxqr gt t
>   swxhjmuhkag mor alglbg zehmccxc hi ibm yyfn oa rhahewu abqb ikuzlq. Bb
>   bfux mmx ng lvxwu vjo zug khbr ivawyd tgzyw olgc ei rhqqgtsuy dnjm fsb
>   mehbccxc.

What could this possibly mean? Are my co-workers playing a prank on me?

**Can you uncover the hidden message?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Using a vigenere cipher method: Always encrypt the next letter with the *decrypted* form of the previous one plus one. For example, if the last decrypted letter was `C`, use `D` as the next shift. For the first letter, just use `a` for no shift. So for the first word the key is `adpohsbevmbujpo`, which yields `Congradulations`.
> The full key is
> `adpohsbevmbujpotpokpjojohuifufbnzpvibwfqspwfozpvstfmgbtbsftpvsdfgvmboexpsuizbeejujpoupuifufbncztpmwjohuijtqvaamfxfxjmmbmmcfhpjohpvugpstpnfesjoltbgufsxpslupdfmfcsbufzpvsofxqptjujp`
> The full decrypted plaintext is
> `Congradulations on joining the team! You have proven yourself as a resourceful and worthy addition to the team by solving this puzzle. We will all be going out for some drinks after work to celebrate your new position.`

Comment: Damn, I was trying exactly this but with the *encrypted* form.

Comment: nice work!  haha but maybe the new guy will miss the drinks hahah

Comment: Nicely done. Not exactly the method I used, but you got the right answer so I'm marking it as correct.

Comment: @R.R.Louw Interesting, I assume you used a ROT-X cipher for every letter, but where the letter is equal to the position in the latin alphabet, not the index (i.e. `A=1, B=2`, etc.))? This way the letter also wouldn't have to be increased by one place like in my solution. I only used the vigenere cipher because then the cipher could be decrypted at once, just with one key.

Comment: Exactly. At least for the encoding. So for the decoding one would have to use the inverse (i.e. encoding: Rot-4, decoding: Rot-22).